# ServiceStack Session timing out in an hour or so

Tags: servicestack

I am using servicestack to develop a restful api.  I also have an ASP.Net web site which consumes this api to create a client side UI (using ajax + CORS).

After successful login (and data being served), if I leave the page idle for about an hour or so, I come back and it redirects me to login.

Here is how I initialize authorization with a 48 hour expiration:

```
    var usernameOnlyAuthProvider = new UsernameOnlyAuthProvider() {SessionExpiry = new System.TimeSpan(48,0,0) };
    var credentialsProvider = new CustomBasicAuthProvider();
    container.Register<IAuthProvider>(credentialsProvider);
    container.Register<CredentialsAuthProvider>(usernameOnlyAuthProvider);
    var authFeature = new AuthFeature(() => new JanrainUserSession(),
                                                  new IAuthProvider[] {
                                                                      usernameOnlyAuthProvider,
                                                                      credentialsProvider
                                                                   }) { HtmlRedirect = null };


//Default route: /auth/{provider}
Plugins.Add(authFeature);
```

What could I be overlooking?

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem, it turned out to be the the Application Pool timeout in IIS.